# Angularjs application in IE11 is not working without F12 developer tools

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a web application working fine with chrome and mozilla. There seems to be a glitch with IE11 and could not load the pages properly with this browser.

When F12 developer mode is active, then it works well in all aspects.

There are no console logs and style attributes which might be problematic with IE11. Still the pages are not loading properly.

Unfortunately i am even not getting any console errors. This section is completely blank.

Application is built on angular1.2 and jquery2.1. IE11 version is 11.0.9600.18124

Comment: Impossible to tell what the problem is - usually Angular just works fine with IE 11. You will need to either trim it down until the problem goes away or first update to Angular 1.4 to see if that helps.

Comment: It could also be a help if there are any frequent possible things that may cause issues!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by updating any http calls with 'get' method to 'post'. There may be a work around if still 'get' method has to be used.

So, by clearing any console logs and updating all http calls to 'post' method resolved the issue.

Comment: Is this the best solution?

Comment: It's the solution I followed. There could be another optimized which I didn't come across.

Comment: Aside from removing console.log and changing get method to post, Is there any other solution, my application is written in Angular 6